# Error: Request failed with status code 400 - AXIOS NODEJS REACTJS EXPRESSJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, axios

I am creating a user authentication site with mern and I am having problem posting to mongoDB. I have tried many options and the problem persists. It gives lots of error messages. I used nodejs, expressjs and mongodb for configuring the backend. Please help me out

[controller]:

```
const User = require('../model/User');
// const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

exports.createUser = async (req,res) => {

try{ 
    // req.body.password = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password,8);
   const user = new User(req.body);
    
    await user.save();

    return res.status(201).json({success: true, user});
}
catch(e){
    return res.status(400).json({success: 
false,message:e.message});
 }
}
```

[route]:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const { createUser,
    getAllUser,
    getSingleUser,
    updateUser,
    deleteUser,
    login} = require('../controller/user');


 // CREATE USER

 router.post('/user',createUser);
```

[module]:

```
const mongoose =  require('mongoose');
const validator = require('validator');
// const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name:{
    type: String,
    minlength: 3,
    unique:true,
    maxlength: 20,
    required:true ,
    trim: true

    },
    age:{
    type:Number,
    validate(value){
        if(value < 18){
            throw new Error(`Age can't be less than 18`)
        }
    }
   },
   email:{
    type:String,
    required:true,
    unique: true,
    lowercase:true,
    trim:true,
    validate(value){
        if(!validator.isEmail(value)){
            throw new Error('Email is not valid');
        }
     }
    },
    password:{
    type:String,
    required:true
    },
    });

   userSchema.pre('save', async function(next){

const user = this;

console.log(user.isModified('password'));

if(user.isModified('password')){
    user.password = await (user.password,8);
}
next();
});

const User  = mongoose.model('User',userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

[form]:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import * as Components from "./FormComponents";
import axios from "axios";
const Signin = (props) => {
const [signIn, toggle] = React.useState(true);
const [createUser,setcreateUser] = useState({
  name:'',
  email:'',
  password:'',
  age:30,
});
useEffect(()=>{
  axios.get('http://localhost:4040/user').then(res => 
console.log(res.data))
},[])
const handleInput = (event) => {
  const {name,value} = event.target;
  setcreateUser({...createUser, [name]:value});
  // console.log(createUser);
 }
 async function handlesubmit(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(createUser);
  try{
    const rep = await axios.post('http://localhost:4040/user',
    {createUser}, {
      headers: {
      'Content-Type': "application/json",
  }})
    .then(Response => console.log(Response))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
    console.log(rep.data);
  }catch(err){
    console.log(err.Response)
  }
}

return(
    <Components.Container>
      <Components.SignUpContainer signingIn={signIn}>
        <Components.Form  onSubmit={handlesubmit}>
          <Components.Title>Create Account</Components.Title>
          <Components.Input type="text" name="name" value={createUser.name} placeholder="Name" onChange={handleInput}/>
          <Components.Input type="email" name="email" value={createUser.email} placeholder="Email" onChange={handleInput}/>
          <Components.Input type="password" name="password" value={createUser.passord} placeholder="Password" onChange={handleInput}/>
          <Components.Input type="number" name="age" value={createUser.age} placeholder="Confirm Password" />
          <Components.Button >Sign Up</Components.Button>
        </Components.Form>
      </Components.SignUpContainer>
```

[dbconnection]:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose =  require('mongoose');
// const colors = require('colors')
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors({
origin: 'http://localhost:3000', // <-- location of the react server
}))

// middleware
app.use(express.json());

var url = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/restmongose';

mongoose.connect(url)
.then(() => console.log("Database Connected Successfully!"))
.catch((err) => console.error(err));

// Schema(Shape of a document)

const userRoutes = require('./routes/user')
const taskRoutes = require('./routes/task')

app.use(userRoutes);
app.use(taskRoutes);

const port = process.env.PORT||4040;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running at port ${port}`));
```

Comment: can you show us your error message ?

Comment: Please share more details including the code.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you send the correct valid age.
In the model, You defined the age should be more than 18.

Comment: yes please. But I can still take that off

Comment: It would be great to show the console log with a screenshot.